# Breaking Python dict output onto new line after certain length

Tags: python, string, dictionary, output, newline

I am trying to find a way to print the values in a dict so that after a certain length (5 for example) the set breaks and continues on a new lines.

**Example:**

```
dict = {'Upper':'ABCDEFGHI', 'Lower':'abcdefghi', 'Number':'123456789'}

def insertNewlines(text, lineLength):
    if len(text) <= lineLength:
        return text
    else:
        return text[:lineLength] + '\n' + insertNewlines(text[lineLength:], lineLength)

for key, val in dict.items():
    print(insertNewlines(val,5))
```

**Output**

```
ABCDE
FGHI
abcde
fghi
12345
6789
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ABCDE
abcde
12345

FGHI
fghi
6789
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What happens if the limit is 5 but the dict key or val is, say, 31 chars and the others are, say, 16, 42, 13, 2 and 22? More examples of the desired behavior would be great that illustrate how to handle arbitrary cases and the underlying algorithm is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all dict values have the same length the following code would give the desired output by taking string slices at increasing intervals.

```
dict = {'Upper':'ABCDEFGHI', 'Lower':'abcdefghi', 'Number':'123456789'}

line_length = 5
value_length = len(next(iter(dict.values())))

count = 0
while count * line_length < value_length:
    for value in dict.values():
        print(value[count * line_length: (count + 1) * line_length])
    print()
    count += 1
```

Or similarly, using a for loop over a range

```
import math
for i in range(math.ceil(value_length / line_length)):
    for value in dict.values():
        print(value[i * line_length: (i + 1) * line_length])
    print()
```